# Android Listview on rebuild not showing new items until scroll down

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

Okay so I have a listview thats populated by pulling JSON data from the web. I wrapped the item in a SwypeRefreshLayout. Whats happening is when I pull down, its fetching the data, clears the Arraylist, rebuilds it and then notifies the adapter of a data set change. However Im not seeing new data right away. In order to see the new items at the top I need to scroll down so its out of view and then back up.

Here is the code I'm using to refresh the List.

```
 swipelists.setOnRefreshListener( new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

                @Override public void onRefresh() {
                    if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3 ) {

                        recentArrayList.clear();
                        long totalSize = 0;
                        recadapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, recentArrayList);

                        new updatetheRecent().execute(ctx);

                    }

                    else {
                        swipelists.setRefreshing(false);
                    }



                }});
```

Here is the function that's being called to rebuild the list

```
 private class updatetheRecent extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(Context... urls) {
            int count = urls.length;


            long totalSize = 0;
            try {



                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://test.net/pltxtrec.php"); 
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
                    sb.append(line + "\n");


                String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(resString);
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String jsonvalues = json_data.getString("title");
                    if (!jsonvalues.equals("")) {
                        recentArrayList.add(json_data.getString("artist") + " - " + json_data.getString("title"));
                        // .. get all value here
                    }




                }
                if (recentArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                    recentArrayList.add("No items currently in queue");
                }


                is.close(); // Close the stream

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        recadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        swipelists.setRefreshing(false);


                    }
                });

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }

            return totalSize;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            if (recentlist != null) {
                // Tried adding this is but its never called
                recentlist.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`, call

```
recadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
swipelists.setRefreshing(false);
```

on the `onPostExecute()` method (that runs on the UI thread).

If this not work, try calling [`invalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) on the SwypeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP Request is an async task, meaning it will return when it returns, you can't draw the content of something that has not yet arrived.

I havent tested it but it looks like what you are looking for is the isRefreshing() method from SwipeRefreshLayout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#isRefreshing()

Comment: The SwipeRefreshLayout is a loader of sorts. Are you talking about something outside of this? Also even with a loader I would need to hide the entirety of the list view, show the loader and then re show the listview instead of it updating like normal.

Comment: Your updatetheRecent class extends AsyncTask which is to say that it will return its value when it is returned to it. Your asking your view to draw content as if the new updatetheRecent().execute(ctx); function would return immediately and it will not. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
runOnUiThread(run);
```

OnCreate(), you set your runnable thread:

```
run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //reload content
        arraylist.clear();
        arraylist.addAll(db.readAll());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.invalidateViews();
        listview.refreshDrawableState();
    }
};
```